# Does 302 redirect supports method forwarding?

Tags: http, protocols, http-protocols

We have a shortcut service in my company which basically provides redirection of short aliases to full URLs. The server runs a simple http redirection (**302**) service which uses the Host request header to a do a lookup with a file system based datastore.

I have a Resful Web Applciation and all the **GET** requests are working ok however **POST/PUT** requests are not reaching to server.

Does 302 "Redirect" by default keep the original requested method or it gets overwritten with GET types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 302 is generally implemented as specified by 303. To keep the original method, use 307 instead.

See also [302](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) section of the [HTTP status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed
>     to change the method on the redirected request.  However, most
>     existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303
>     response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless
>     of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have
>     been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which
>     kind of reaction is expected of the client.

The [303](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) specifies that the new location should be requested by GET. The [307](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.8) keeps the original method.

Comment: You might want to look at the more-recent <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-22.html#status.302>

Comment: @Julian: it's still a draft, but in that draft, the 307 specifies *"... and the user agent MUST NOT change the request method..."* which is exactly what the OP needs (and already answered by my answer).

Comment: @Balucs: it's a draft in Last Call, and it's 12 years never. It describes reality much better than RFC 2616.

Answer (score 1):

For 302, POST is always rewritten to GET. Other methods sometimes (depending on how broken the browser is, see http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc/httpredirects/).